# Pandas - What is the fastest way to count values greater than x in a rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas Series `a`, for each value `a[i]` I need count how many values in `a[i-window:i-1]` are greater than `a[i]`

The code below does the job through a python for loop, which is slow on serious computational tasks

Does Pandas offer a similar functionality, possibly wrapping some optimised Numpy function?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

window = 30                              # any arbitrary window
a = pandas.Series(np.random.rand(100))   # dummy variable, arbitrary length

counter = pandas.Series(data=np.NaN, index=a.index)

for i in a.index[window:]:
    counter[i] = (a[i-window:i-1] < a[i]).sum()

print counter
```

Comment: a.rolling(window).count() I think. I'm on a phone and can't verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.rolling_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

window = 30
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100), columns=['Data'])

counts = pd.rolling_apply(df, window+1, lambda s: s[s < s[-1]].shape[0])
```

Make sure to add one to the window size.

Comment: Thanks, so that in pandas 0.18+ would be `df.rolling(window=window+1).apply(lambda: s: (s < s[-1]).sum()))` I presume

Comment: Is there possibly a faster way to count than summing boolean values?

Comment: I am not at my computer but I suggest trying to filter/shape. Also maybe some algorithmic optimization using ranks.

Comment: I thought about tiling the array horizontally `np.tile(a, (window,1)).T` and then doing horizontal calculations. Any advice welcome, thanks anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. I spent some time trying to improve on this by cutting redundant comparisons. The idea is to keep a sorted list with length of window size, and add/remove elements using bisections. My implementation was still much slower than this, however, even for larger windows. Perhaps the above approach can be well-implemented in cython. BTW I modified the answer btw to avoid summing bools.